# trying bypassing htaccess based basic http authentication

Tags: authentication, penetration-test, http, apache, web

I am trying to solve this [web challenge](http://htaccess.hacking.w3challs.com/) which requires to bypass an htaccess based form authentication. after some research i tried to change the request to

```
GETS /admin/ HTTP/1.1
Host: htaccess.hacking.w3challs.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

from the original header

```
GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1
Host: htaccess.hacking.w3challs.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

using Burp suite, but I am still not able to bypass the authentication form. any tips what's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Why did you change the method to the invalid `GETS`?

Comment: i read read an article describing  that if we use any other method instead of get or post then the request will not be validated  due to not using <LimitExcept GET POST>  properly.

Answer (score 4):

This simply means that the server is not vulnerable in the way you are expecting it to be (using `GETS` instead of `GET` to bypass black-listing of HTTP verbs).

I tried passing a path like: http://htaccess.hacking.w3challs.com/?page=/.htaccess
and directory traversal seems to be possible. Try looking for a .htpasswd file somewhere in the directory tree.

Answer (score 2):

The use of verb juggling or a mangled HTTP verb like GETS to bypass authentication requires 2 configuration options on the server (Apache example provided).

1. Authentication must be implemented with a `<Limit VERB VERB VERB>` directive. As this only enforces authentication for the listed verbs. If the restrictions only cover `GET` and `POST` for example you can bypass this with ver juggling (use `PUT` instead of `POST`)
2. If you cannot juggle a verb you may be able to juggle anyway by using a mangled verb such as `GETS` instead of `GET`. However this is only possible if the application handler allows unknown verbs or does a bad job validating known verbs (such as the php script handler).

If the authentication is implemented without this variation of the `<Limit>` directive there are no known bypasses that I'm aware of.